# Mount Google Cloud Storage in a Custom Flex GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, storage, persistence, volume, bucket

I have a web application in a Custom Runtime Flex App Engine, which is deploy from a docker image, working fine.

This app is connected to a db in Google Cloud SQL to data persistence.

Now I trying to persist file data in a Cloud Storage Bucket, but I do not have found the way to mount this storage like a file system.

Gcsfuse does not work in this case due to privileges are required to tun docker.

In the app.yaml you can specify a volume, but not associate to storage.

How can persist file data with cloud storage in a Custom Flex GAE app?

Comment: why do not call the Cloud Storage API from your app to save the files?

Comment: You can't mount cloud storage.  You use the API.